# Pagination with placeholder cakephp 3.X

Tags: php, pagination, placeholder

I have searched for 2 days, but found no answer. I use a query with  placeholders (%$string%) for searching customers.

In the Controller:

```
  ` public function searchName()
        {      
            $data = $this->Kunden->find()->where([
                'Kunden.name LIKE' => '%'.\filter_input(\INPUT_POST, 'name', \FILTER_DEFAULT).'%']);
        $this->set(\compact('data'), $this->paginate($data));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['data']);

        }
`
```

In the search_name.ctp:

```
    <?php foreach ($data as $suche): ?>
         <tr>
            <td><?= $this->Number->format($suche->Kundennummer,['precision' => 0, 'pattern' => '####']) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($suche->Anrede) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($suche->Name) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($suche->Vorname) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($suche->Ansprechpartner) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($suche->Strasse_Nr) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($suche->PLZ) ?></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $suche->Kundennummer]) ?>
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $suche->Kundennummer]) ?>

            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
   <?php
        $this->Paginator->options(array(
        'url' => array(
        'data' => $data)));
      ?>
    <div class="paginator">
        <ul class="pagination">

            <?= $this->Paginator->first('<< ' . __('erste Seite')) ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('vor')) ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->last('>> ' . __('letzte Seite')) ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->number(' ' . __('gehe zu Seite:')) ?>
        </ul>
        <p><?= $this->Paginator->counter() ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first page shows a list of customers found by %$string%, but in the next pages I get all customers from the table.

I print the array $data foreach pagebuildung, the value of the placeholder changes from the first to the second page.

first page: ... LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 [params] => Array ( [:c0] => Array ( [value] => **%ab%** [type] => [placeholder] => c0 )...

second page: ... LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10 [params] => Array ( [:c0] => Array ( [value] => **%%** [type] => [placeholder] => c0 ) ...

What can I do to keep the value ?

Thank you for help ..

Comment: String templates have nothing to do with queries. What is your issue? It is not clear from your question. What is the executed query and how should it be built?

Comment: for example: I search all customers with %ab% in the name. Without pagination i get a list with ~ 50 customers with 'ab' in their name. When  i paginat with limit "10" the first 10 customers have "ab" und the pagecounter shows 5 pages. When i go to the second page i get customers also without "ab" und the counter shows 350 pages, that is the  number of the pages for all customers. By creating the second page the value of the placeholder is lost, so all customers will be shown ...

Comment: The query is build in searchName(), s.o.. The $string comes from a form via post. When i don't use post and write :  $data = $this->Kunden->find()->where([ 'Kunden.name LIKE' => "%ab%"]); t works fine for all pages

Comment: OK, for creating the second page, the query is done again. But now the $_POST is empty, because the query is not called from the form, but from the paginator...  How can i give the value with ?